# Matrix implementation with Rank and Inverse calculation using Gaussian Elimination in Java

Tags: java, matrix, mathematics

## Disclaimer

Some things that I must state:

1. *This is just for practice.* I want to know the various algorithms in linear algebra in detail.
2. *I will not use this in a practical scenario.* Except for verifying my assignment solutions. Consequently, there is a slim probability that I'll be provided with inputs that lead to numerical instability. However, I'd like my code to be able to handle it.

## The code

### `Matrix.java`

Contains the entire codebase. Probably needs to be split up.

```
package com.github.subh0m0y.matrix;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Random;

import static com.github.subh0m0y.matrix.Standards.EPSILON;

@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")
public class Matrix {
    public static final String FORMAT_STRING = "%+.2e";
    private final int rows;
    private final int cols;
    private final double[][] data;

    /**
     * Creates a new matrix with the given data
     *
     * @param data         The raw data to encapsulate.
     * @param makeDeepCopy Whether to copy every element or use the given reference.
     */
    Matrix(final double[][] data, final boolean makeDeepCopy) {
        this.rows = data.length;
        this.cols = this.rows == 0 ? 0 : data[0].length;

        if (makeDeepCopy) {
            this.data = new double[rows][cols];
            for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
                System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, this.data[i], 0, cols);
            }
        } else {
            this.data = data;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new zero matrix of order rows x cols.
     *
     * @param rows The number of rows required.
     * @param cols The number of columns required.
     */
    Matrix(final int rows, final int cols) {
        if (rows < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number of rows : " + rows);
        }
        if (cols < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number of columns : " + cols);
        }
        this.rows = rows;
        this.cols = cols;
        data = new double[rows][cols];
    }

    /**
     * Creates a new Matrix that is a copy of the given
     * matrix and is independent of the original.
     *
     * @param matrix The matrix to copy.
     */
    public Matrix(final Matrix matrix) {
        rows = matrix.rows;
        cols = matrix.cols;
        data = new double[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(matrix.data[i], 0, data[i], 0, cols);
        }
    }

    public static Matrix fromArray(final double[][] data) {
        return new Matrix(data, true);
    }

    public static Matrix zero(final int rows, final int cols) {
        return new Matrix(rows, cols);
    }

    public static Matrix identity(final int order) {
        double[][] data = new double[order][order];
        for (int i = 0; i < order; i++) {
            data[i][i] = 1;
        }
        return new Matrix(data, false);
    }

    public static Matrix fromLinearArray(final int rows, final int cols,
                                         final double... elements) {
        if (elements.length != rows * cols) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid number of elements: " + elements.length
                    + " Expected: " + rows * cols);
        }
        double[][] data = new double[rows][cols];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(elements, i * cols, data[i], 0, cols);
        }
        return new Matrix(data, false);
    }

    public static Matrix random(final int rows, final int cols) {
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(rows, cols);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                matrix.data[i][j] = random.nextDouble();
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

    public int getRows() {
        return rows;
    }

    public int getCols() {
        return cols;
    }

    public double get(final int i, final int j) throws IndexOutOfBoundsException {
        if (i < 0 || i >= rows) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid row index : " + i);
        }
        if (j < 0 || j >= cols) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid column index : " + i);
        }
        return data[i][j];
    }

    public double[] getRow(final int row) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throwIfInvalidIndex(row, rows, "row");
        return Arrays.copyOf(data[row], cols);
    }

    public double[] getColumn(final int column) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throwIfInvalidIndex(column, cols, "column");
        double[] col = new double[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            col[i] = data[i][column];
        }
        return col;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof Matrix)) return false;
        Matrix matrix = (Matrix) o;
        return rows == matrix.rows &&
                cols == matrix.cols &&
                Arrays.deepEquals(data, matrix.data);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = Objects.hash(rows, cols);
        result = 31 * result + Arrays.deepHashCode(data);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        if (rows == 0 || cols == 0) {
            return "";
        }
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            if (i == 0) {
                builder.append(" /");
            } else if (i == rows - 1) {
                builder.append(" \\");
            } else {
                builder.append("| ");
            }
            builder.append(String.format(FORMAT_STRING, data[i][0]));
            for (int j = 1; j < cols; j++) {
                builder.append(", ");
                builder.append(String.format(FORMAT_STRING, data[i][j]));
            }
            if (i == 0) {
                builder.append("\\");
            } else if (i == rows - 1) {
                builder.append("/");
            } else {
                builder.append(" |");
            }
            builder.append("\n");
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    public boolean isZero() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (data[i][j] != 0) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isSquare() {
        return rows == cols;
    }

    public boolean isUpperTriangular() {
        if (!isSquare()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                if (Math.abs(data[i][j]) > EPSILON) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isLowerTriangular() {
        if (!isSquare()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < cols; j++) {
                if (Math.abs(data[i][j]) > EPSILON) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public boolean isDiagonal() {
        return isLowerTriangular() && isUpperTriangular();
    }

    public boolean isIdentity() {
        if (!isDiagonal()) {
            return false;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(data[i][i] - 1) > EPSILON) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void transposeInPlace() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
                double temp = data[i][j];
                data[i][j] = data[j][i];
                data[j][i] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix transpose() {
        Matrix transpose = new Matrix(rows, cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                transpose.data[j][i] = data[i][j];
            }
        }
        return transpose;
    }

    public void zeroFill() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                if (Math.abs(data[i][j]) < EPSILON) {
                    data[i][j] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void scaleInPlace(final double scale) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                data[i][j] *= scale;
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix scale(final double scale) {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(this);
        temp.scaleInPlace(scale);
        return temp;
    }

    private void throwIncompatible(String operation) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Given matrix is not compatible with the invoking matrix for "
                + operation);
    }

    public void addInPlace(final Matrix addend) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (addend.rows != rows || addend.cols != cols) {
            throwIncompatible("addition");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                data[i][j] += addend.data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix add(final Matrix addend) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(this);
        temp.addInPlace(addend);
        return temp;
    }

    public void subtractInPlace(final Matrix addend) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (addend.rows != rows || addend.cols != cols) {
            throwIncompatible("subtraction");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                data[i][j] -= addend.data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix subtract(final Matrix addend) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(this);
        temp.subtractInPlace(addend);
        return temp;
    }

    public void multiplyInPlace(final Matrix multiplicand) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (multiplicand.rows != rows || multiplicand.cols != cols) {
            throwIncompatible("addition");
        }
        double[][] product = new double[rows][cols];
        storeProduct(multiplicand, product);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(product[i], 0, data[i], 0, cols);
        }
    }

    public Matrix multiply(final Matrix multiplicand) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (multiplicand.rows != cols) {
            throwIncompatible("multiplication");
        }
        double[][] product = new double[rows][cols];
        storeProduct(multiplicand, product);
        return new Matrix(product, false);
    }

    private void storeProduct(Matrix multiplicand, double[][] product) {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < multiplicand.cols; j++) {
                product[i][j] = 0;
                for (int k = 0; k < cols; k++) {
                    product[i][j] += data[i][k] * multiplicand.data[k][j];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void elementMultiplyInPlace(final Matrix matrix) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (matrix.rows != rows || matrix.cols != cols) {
            throwIncompatible("element-wise multiplication");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                data[i][j] *= matrix.data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix elementMultiply(final Matrix matrix) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(this);
        temp.elementMultiplyInPlace(matrix);
        return temp;
    }

    public void elementDivideInPlace(final Matrix matrix) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (matrix.rows != rows || matrix.cols != cols) {
            throwIncompatible("element-wise multiplication");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
                data[i][j] /= matrix.data[i][j];
            }
        }
    }

    public Matrix elementDivide(final Matrix matrix) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(this);
        temp.elementDivideInPlace(matrix);
        return temp;
    }

    public Matrix exponentiate(int power) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (!isSquare()) {
            throwIncompatible("exponentiation");
        }
        if (power < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Power cannot be negative.");
        }
        Matrix product = Matrix.identity(rows);
        Matrix x = new Matrix(this);
        while (power > 0) {
            if ((power & 1) == 1) {
                product.multiplyInPlace(x);
            }
            x.multiplyInPlace(x);
            power >>= 1;
        }
        return product;
    }

    public boolean isOrthogonal() {
        Matrix value = multiply(transpose());
        value.zeroFill();
        return value.isIdentity();
    }

    public boolean isInvolutary() {
        Matrix value = multiply(this);
        value.zeroFill();
        return value.isIdentity();
    }

    public Matrix appendRight(final Matrix matrix) {
        if (matrix.rows != rows) {
            throwIncompatible("appending right");
        }
        Matrix store = new Matrix(rows, cols + matrix.cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, store.data[i], 0, cols);
            System.arraycopy(matrix.data[i], 0, store.data[i], cols, matrix.cols);
        }
        return store;
    }

    public Matrix appendBottom(final Matrix matrix) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (matrix.cols != cols) {
            throwIncompatible("appending right");
        }
        Matrix store = new Matrix(rows + matrix.rows, cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, store.data[i], 0, cols);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.rows; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(matrix.data[i], 0, store.data[i + rows], 0, cols);
        }
        return store;
    }

    private void throwIfInvalidIndex(int value, int limit, String quantity) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        if (value <= 0 || value > limit) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid " + quantity + " index : " + value);
        }
    }

    public Matrix[] splitAtColumn(final int column) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throwIfInvalidIndex(column, cols, "column");
        int columnResidue = cols - column;
        Matrix left = new Matrix(rows, column);
        Matrix right = new Matrix(rows, columnResidue);
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, left.data[i], 0, column);
            System.arraycopy(data[i], column, right.data[i], 0, columnResidue);
        }
        return new Matrix[]{left, right};
    }

    public Matrix[] splitAtRow(final int row) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throwIfInvalidIndex(row, rows, "row");
        int rowResidue = rows - row;
        Matrix top = new Matrix(row, cols);
        Matrix bottom = new Matrix(rowResidue, cols);
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, top.data[i], 0, cols);
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rowResidue; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(data[i + row], 0, bottom.data[i], 0, cols);
        }
        return new Matrix[]{top, bottom};
    }

    public void swapRowsInPlace(final int row1, final int row2) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throwIfInvalidIndex(row1, rows, "row");
        throwIfInvalidIndex(row2, rows, "row");
        double[] row = new double[cols];
        System.arraycopy(data[row1], 0, row, 0, cols);
        System.arraycopy(data[row2], 0, data[row1], 0, cols);
        System.arraycopy(row, 0, data[row2], 0, cols);
    }

    public Matrix swapRows(final int row1, final int row2) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(this);
        temp.swapRowsInPlace(row1, row2);
        return temp;
    }

    public void swapColumnsInPlace(int col1, int col2) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        throwIfInvalidIndex(col1, rows, "column");
        throwIfInvalidIndex(col2, rows, "column");
        double[] column = new double[rows];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            column[i] = data[i][col1];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            data[i][col1] = data[i][col2];
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            data[i][col2] = column[i];
        }
    }

    public Matrix swapColumns(final int col1, final int col2) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Matrix temp = new Matrix(this);
        temp.swapColumnsInPlace(col1, col2);
        return temp;
    }

    private void checkLen(double[] doubles, int len) {
        if (doubles.length != len) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "Invalid number of elements. Expected : " + len + " Found : " + doubles.length
            );
        }
    }

    private void addScaledRow(double scale, double[] row, int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            data[index][i] += row[i] * scale;
        }
    }

    private void scaleRow(double scale, int index) {
        for (int i = 0; i < cols; i++) {
            data[index][i] *= scale;
        }
    }

    public void convertToReducedRowEchelon() {
        int limit = Math.min(rows, cols);
        // Cascade from the top left corner downwards and rightwards
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            double factor = data[i][i];
            for (int j = i + 1; j < rows; j++) {
                // Make all the rows below the ith row have zeros in the ith column
                addScaledRow(-data[j][i] / factor, data[i], j);
            }
            // Normalize to make sure that the leading number in every row is 1
            scaleRow(1 / data[i][i], i);
        }
    }

    public void convertEchelonToNormal() {
        int limit = Math.min(rows, cols);
        // Cascade from the bottom right part of original matrix upwards and leftwards
        for (int i = limit - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            double factor = data[i][i];
            for (int j = i - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                // Make all the rows above the ith row have zeros in the ith column
                addScaledRow(-1 / factor, data[i], j);
            }
        }
    }

    private Matrix rowReducedForm = null;

    public int getRank() {
        if (rowReducedForm == null) {
            rowReducedForm = new Matrix(this);
            rowReducedForm.convertToReducedRowEchelon();
        }
        int zeroRows = 0, limit = Math.min(rows, cols);
        outer:
        for (double[] row : rowReducedForm.data) {
            for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
                if (Math.abs(row[i]) > EPSILON) {
                    continue outer;
                }
            }
            zeroRows++;
        }
        return limit - zeroRows;
    }

    private Matrix inverse = null;

    public Matrix getInverse() throws ArithmeticException {
        if (inverse != null) {
            return inverse;
        }
        if (!isSquare()) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot find inverse of a non-square matrix.");
        }
        Matrix augmented = appendRight(Matrix.identity(rows));
        int rank = augmented.getRank();
        if (rank < rows) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Cannot find inverse of singular matrix.");
        }
        augmented.convertEchelonToNormal();
        Matrix[] matrices = augmented.splitAtColumn(cols);
        rowReducedForm = matrices[0];
        inverse = matrices[1];
        return inverse;
    }
}
```

### `Standards.java`

Contains accessible constants used throughout the system. Will be expanded. Or removed completely.

package com.github.subh0m0y.matrix;

```
public class Standards {
    public static double EPSILON = 1.0e-14;
}
```

## Test cases

There should probably be more cases with more corner cases. I used the TestNG framework here.

### `BasicMatrixTest.java`

```
package com.github.subh0m0y.matrix;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Random;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

public class BasicMatrixTest {
    private static final int ROWS = 100;
    private static final int COLS = 100;
    private static Random random;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        random = new Random();
    }

    private static void changeElement(double[][] data, Random random) {
        data[random.nextInt(ROWS)][random.nextInt(COLS)] *= random.nextGaussian() * 2;
        data[random.nextInt(ROWS)][random.nextInt(COLS)] += random.nextGaussian() + 1;
    }

    @Test
    public void testEqualsAndHashCode() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(matrix1);
        assertTrue(matrix1.equals(matrix2));
        assertEquals(matrix1.hashCode(), matrix2.hashCode());
        changeElement(data, random);
        assertFalse(matrix1.equals(matrix2));
        assertNotEquals(matrix1.hashCode(), matrix2.hashCode());
    }

    @Test
    public void testConstructors() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Matrix matrixZero1 = new Matrix(ROWS, COLS);
        Matrix matrixZero2 = new Matrix(data, true);

        assertTrue(matrixZero1.isZero());
        assertTrue(matrixZero2.isZero());
        assertEquals(matrixZero1, matrixZero2);

        Utilities.populate(data, random);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, true);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data, false);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix2);

        changeElement(data, random);
        assertNotEquals(matrix1, matrix2);

        Matrix matrix3 = new Matrix(matrix1);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testFromArray() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data, random);
        double[] linear = new double[ROWS * COLS];
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            System.arraycopy(data[i], 0, linear, i * COLS, COLS);
        }
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = Matrix.fromArray(data);
        Matrix matrix3 = Matrix.fromLinearArray(ROWS, COLS, linear);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix2);
        assertEquals(matrix2, matrix3);
        changeElement(data, random);
        assertNotEquals(matrix1, matrix2);
        assertNotEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGet() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data, random);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(matrix1);

        assertEquals(matrix1.getRows(), ROWS);
        assertEquals(matrix1.getCols(), COLS);
        assertEquals(matrix2.getRows(), ROWS);
        assertEquals(matrix2.getCols(), COLS);

        assertEquals(matrix1.getRows(), matrix2.getRows());
        assertEquals(matrix1.getCols(), matrix2.getCols());

        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                assertEquals(matrix1.get(i, j), matrix2.get(i, j));
            }
        }
        assertThrows(() -> matrix1.get(-1, 0));
        assertThrows(() -> matrix2.get(0, COLS));
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsZero() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);
        assertTrue(matrix1.isZero());
        changeElement(data, random);
        assertFalse(matrix1.isZero());
        Matrix matrix2 = Matrix.zero(ROWS, COLS);
        assertTrue(matrix2.isZero());
    }

    @Test
    public void testIsIdentity() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][ROWS];
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);
        assertFalse(matrix1.isIdentity());
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            data[i][i] = 1;
        }
        assertTrue(matrix1.isSquare());
        assertTrue(matrix1.isIdentity());
        changeElement(data, random);
        assertFalse(matrix1.isIdentity());

        Matrix matrix2 = Matrix.identity(ROWS);
        assertTrue(matrix2.isIdentity());
    }

    @Test
    public void testZeroFill() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < COLS; j++) {
                data[i][j] = random.nextDouble() * Standards.EPSILON;
            }
        }
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix(data, false);
        assertFalse(matrix.isZero());
        matrix.zeroFill();
        assertTrue(matrix.isZero());
    }

    @Test
    public void testTranspose() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = matrix1.transpose();
        matrix1.transposeInPlace();
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testAppendingAndSplitting() {
        Matrix matrix1 = Matrix.random(ROWS, COLS);
        Matrix matrix2 = Matrix.random(ROWS, COLS);
        Matrix matrixHorizontal = matrix1.appendRight(matrix2);
        Matrix matrixVertical = matrix1.appendBottom(matrix2);
        Matrix[] horizontal = matrixHorizontal.splitAtColumn(COLS);
        Matrix[] vertical = matrixVertical.splitAtRow(ROWS);
        assertEquals(matrix1, horizontal[0]);
        assertEquals(matrix2, horizontal[1]);
        assertEquals(matrix1, vertical[0]);
        assertEquals(matrix2, vertical[1]);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSwapAndGetRow() {
        Matrix matrix1 = Matrix.random(ROWS, COLS);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(matrix1);
        int row1 = random.nextInt(ROWS);
        int row2 = random.nextInt(ROWS);
        matrix1.swapRowsInPlace(row1, row2);
        Matrix matrix3 = matrix2.swapRows(row1, row2);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
        assertEquals(matrix1.getRow(row1), matrix2.getRow(row2));
        assertEquals(matrix1.getRow(row2), matrix2.getRow(row1));
    }

    @Test
    public void testSwapAndGetColumn() {
        Matrix matrix1 = Matrix.random(ROWS, COLS);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(matrix1);
        int col1 = random.nextInt(ROWS);
        int col2 = random.nextInt(ROWS);
        matrix1.swapColumnsInPlace(col1, col2);
        Matrix matrix3 = matrix2.swapColumns(col1, col2);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
        assertEquals(matrix1.getColumn(col1), matrix2.getColumn(col2));
        assertEquals(matrix1.getColumn(col2), matrix2.getColumn(col1));
    }
}
```

### `MatrixMathTest.java`

```
package com.github.subh0m0y.matrix;

import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.util.Random;

import static org.testng.Assert.*;

public class MatrixMathTest {

    private static final int ROWS = 100;
    private static final int COLS = 100;
    private static final int POWER_BOUND = 1000;
    private static final int COUNT = 10;

    private static Random random;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() {
        random = new Random();
    }

    @Test
    public void testAddition() {
        double[][] data1 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        double[][] data2 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data1, random);
        Utilities.populate(data2, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix3 = matrix1.add(matrix2);
        matrix1.addInPlace(matrix2);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testSubtraction() {
        double[][] data1 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        double[][] data2 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data1, random);
        Utilities.populate(data2, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix3 = matrix1.subtract(matrix2);
        matrix1.subtractInPlace(matrix2);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testElementMultiply() {
        double[][] data1 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        double[][] data2 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data1, random);
        Utilities.populate(data2, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix3 = matrix1.elementMultiply(matrix2);
        matrix1.elementMultiplyInPlace(matrix2);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testElementDivide() {
        double[][] data1 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        double[][] data2 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
        Utilities.populate(data1, random);
        Utilities.populate(data2, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix3 = matrix1.elementDivide(matrix2);
        matrix1.elementDivideInPlace(matrix2);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testMultiplication() {
        double[][] data1 = new double[ROWS][ROWS];
        double[][] data2 = new double[ROWS][ROWS];
        Utilities.populate(data1, random);
        Utilities.populate(data2, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix3 = matrix1.multiply(matrix2);
        matrix1.multiplyInPlace(matrix2);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix3);
    }

    @Test
    public void testScale() {
        double[][] data1 = new double[ROWS][ROWS];
        double scale = random.nextDouble();
        Utilities.populate(data1, random);
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = matrix1.scale(scale);
        matrix1.scaleInPlace(scale);
        assertEquals(matrix1, matrix2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExponentiation() {
        double[][] data = new double[ROWS][ROWS];
        Utilities.populate(data, random);
        int power = random.nextInt(POWER_BOUND);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data, true);
        Matrix product = Matrix.identity(ROWS);
        for (int i = 0; i < power; i++) {
            product.multiplyInPlace(matrix1);
        }
        matrix2 = matrix2.exponentiate(power);
        assertEquals(product, matrix2);
    }

    @Test
    public void testOrthogonal() {
        for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) {
            Matrix matrix = Matrix.identity(ROWS);
            assertTrue(matrix.isOrthogonal());
            double theta = random.nextDouble() * Math.PI * 2;
            double cos = Math.cos(theta);
            double sin = Math.sin(theta);
            matrix = Matrix.fromLinearArray(2, 2, cos, -sin, sin, cos);
            assertTrue(matrix.isOrthogonal());
            matrix = Matrix.fromLinearArray(2, 2, cos, sin, sin, -cos);
            assertTrue(matrix.isOrthogonal());
        }
    }
}
```

## Requests

Besides all general aspects, I'd like some guidance on what to do next? Pointers on how to implement a method or algorithm in a more effective way will also be appreciated. Things to do to avoid numerical stability is also on my mind. Suggestions for more test cases are also welcome.

## Links

1. IDE - IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (Student License) - [Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)
2. Building software - Apache Maven - [Link](https://maven.apache.org/)
3. Testing framework - TestNG - [Link](http://testng.org/doc/)
4. GitHub Repo - [Link](https://github.com/Subh0m0y/Matrix-Reboot)

Note that 2 and 3 are well integrated into 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code is very good looking:)

Some nitpicks about the main code :

1) factory methods : There are quite a lot of factory methods here, you should consider putting them in an outside class (`MatrixFactory` or `MatrixBuilder`).

2) Random : you should avoid using `new Random` when possible because it :

1. makes for a weaker random variance (the entropy comes from using `next` a lot, creating a new Random instances don't have much entropy as it is based on current time)
2. is harder to test
3. cannot be subclasses with a better randomization algorithm (the period of the default Random implementation is only 2^48 :/ )

You can correct the first point by using the `ThreadLocalRandom` class (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html)
You can correct the following two points by using more injections.

The following code snippets show a potential combination that answers all previous points :

```
public static Matrix random(final int rows, final int cols) {
    return new random(rows, cols, ThreadLocalRandom.current());
}

public static Matrix random(final int rows, final int cols, final Random random) {
    // TODO
```

3) You aren't checking that the `double` given to your constructors/factory methods aren't set to `NaN`. `NaN` can (and will) really mess with any calculations and should be removed/avoided if possible, so I'd consider testing for the presence of this troublemakers

4) I'd consider using stream when applicable :
For example with the all zero method :

```
public boolean isZero() {
    return Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToDouble(rows -> Arrays.stream(rows)).allMatch(v -> v == 0);
}
```

For NaN testing :

```
public boolean containsNaN() {
    return Arrays.stream(data).flatMapToDouble(rows -> Arrays.stream(rows)).anyMatch(Double::isNaN);
}
```

5) I'd actually give up on most (if not all) methods that mutate the Matrix unless you have a good reason not too. It makes some of your code **thread-unsafe**, makes your Matrix basically not insertable in a `Set` (as the hashCode will also be affected) and disallow some nice optimizations (like putting the `toString` or `isDiagonal` results in a cache)

6) Put all your fields at the top of your class (for example the cache field `private Matrix rowReducedForm = null;`)

7) Some people (me included) never indicate whetever their methods throw runtime exceptions and I think you should remove all `throws` from your methods signature, it basically doesn't give much informations and reduce readability

8) Talking about exceptions : I'd consider using `NumberFormatException` and `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when necessary instead of the plain `IllegalArgumentException`

9) Turn private methods that don't access any fields in `private static` method

10) I see some problems here :

```
private Matrix rowReducedForm = null;

public int getRank() {
    if (rowReducedForm == null) {
        rowReducedForm = new Matrix(this);
        rowReducedForm.convertToReducedRowEchelon();
    }
    int zeroRows = 0, limit = Math.min(rows, cols);
    outer:
    for (double[] row : rowReducedForm.data) {
        for (int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
            if (Math.abs(row[i]) > EPSILON) {
                continue outer;
            }
        }
        zeroRows++;
    }
    return limit - zeroRows;
}
```

You are putting a value in cache (which is cool BTW) but since your object is mutable, you may have strange behaviours. You should either remove the cache manually in all methods that do a mutation, remove mutation altogether (**recommended :P**) or remove the cache.
Avoid declaring two variables on the same line and don't use label (they basically are `goto`s). You should be able to solve this by using the `anyMatch` method from `Stream` ;)

11) Lastly, I find it more readable when the `toString`/`equals`/`hashCode` methods are at the very end of the class

12) Your `isOrthogonal` and `isInvolutary` methods are bugged IMO as they use `zeroFill`

13) The `checkLen` method is not used anywhere and, thus, should be removed

Now onto the tests classes !

1) Basically, the same as before : avoid using `new Random` for every test, you can replace the

```
private static Random random;

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    random = new Random();
}
```

by the simpler `private static final Random random = new Random();`

2) I think the `BasicMatrixTest` is fine overall, but maybe you should consider checking the `EqualsVerifier` library that do all necessary checks on the `equals` and `hashcode` methods ;)

3) however, the `MatrixMathTest` doesn't test much :s Most of your tests are basically comparing the result from your mutable methods with the result of the immutable variant of you methods... so if both are bugged, then your test may pass while it should not. The only tests that are real tests are testExponentiation and testOrthogonal

Consider creating some tests with matrix (with random values) for the operations with "special behaviours" :

1. for additions : one test that prove that a matrix M + a matrix full of zeroes give the matrix M
2. for scale : one test that proves that a matrix M * 0 is a matrix full of zeroes
3. for scale : one test that proves that a matrix M * 1 is the matrix M
4. for multiplications : one test that proves that a matrix M * a matrix full of zeroes give the matrix full of zeroes
5. for multiplications : one test that proves that a matrix M * the identity matrix is the matrix M
6. for additions : one test that prove that a matrix A + a matrix B gives the same result as a matrix B + the matrix A
7. for additions and multiplications and scale : show that your method(s) are associative
8. for division : show that your method(s) are NOT associative

Once you have tested the basic **properties** of the matrix's operators do 1 or 2 tests for each operators with constants matrixes ; for example testing the result of matrix [[1, 2] [3, 4]] + matrix [[17, 42] [42, 0]] (with no random value)

Here are some tests examples :

```
@Test
public void addShouldHaveNoEffectWithZeroMatrix() {
    double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {

        Utilities.populate(data, random);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);

        Matrix res = matrix1.add(Matrix.zero(ROWS, COLS));

        assertEquals(matrix1, res);
    }
}

@Test
public void addShouldGiveSameResultNoMatterTheCallOrder() {
    double[][] data1 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
    double[][] data2 = new double[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Utilities.populate(data1, random);
        Utilities.populate(data2, random);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data2, false);

        Matrix res12 = matrix1.add(matrix2);
        Matrix res21 = matrix2.add(matrix1);

        assertEquals(res12, res21);
    }
}

@Test
public void scaleShouldReturnTheZeroMatrixWith0() {
    double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Utilities.populate(data, random);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);

        Matrix res = matrix1.scale(0);

        assertEquals(Matrix.zero(ROWS, COLS), res);
    }
}

@Test
public void scaleShouldReturnTheSameMatrixWith1() {
    double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Utilities.populate(data, random);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);

        Matrix res = matrix1.scale(1);

        assertEquals(matrix1, res);
    }
}

@Test
public void multiplyShouldReturnTheZeroMatrixWithTheZeroMatrix() {
    double[][] data = new double[ROWS][COLS];
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        Utilities.populate(data, random);

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data, false);

        Matrix allZeroes = Matrix.zero(ROWS, COLS);

        Matrix res = matrix1.multiply(allZeroes);

        assertEquals(allZeroes, res);
    }
}

@Test
public void addShouldWorkWithSquareMatrixes() {
    double[][] data1 = { { 17, 24, 0 }, { 0.54, 42, 0 }, { 0, 0, 1 } };
    double[][] data2 = { { 23, 5.5, 0 }, { -3, 5.5, 238 }, { 18.2, 5.5, 1 } };
    double[][] expectedData = { { 40, 29.5, 0 }, { -2.46, 47.5, 238 }, { 18.2, 5.5, 2 } };

    Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
    Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data2, false);
    Matrix expected = new Matrix(expectedData, false);

    Matrix res = matrix1.add(matrix2);

    assertEquals(expected, res);
}
```

**[EDIT]** : your multiply method contains a bug when multiplying differently sized matrixes as can be proven by these two unit test :

```
    @Test
    public void multiplyShouldWorkWithDifferentSizedMatrix() {
        double[][] data1 = { { 21, 42, 0, 50, 1 } };
        double[][] data2 = { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 3 }, { 4 }, { 5 } };
        double[][] expectedData = { { 310 } };

        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(data1, false);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(data2, false);
        Matrix expected = new Matrix(expectedData, false);

        Matrix res = matrix1.multiply(matrix2);

        assertEquals(expected, res);
    }

    @Test
    public void multiplyShouldWorkWithTheEmptyMatrix() {
        Matrix matrix1 = new Matrix(5, 0);
        Matrix matrix2 = new Matrix(0, 0);
        Matrix expected = new Matrix(0, 0);

        Matrix res = matrix1.multiply(matrix2);

        assertEquals(expected, res);
    }
```

Comment: I was debating whether I should opt for immutability. I suppose I could keep the mutable methods to favor performance when creating several instances would be wasteful, but make them private. The immutable API would be exposed and shouldn't be a cause for concern, I hope.

Comment: @Astrobleme yup making them private could be a good idea and would be easy to implement from the existing code (be careful about thread-safety though)

Comment: @Astrobleme i've found a bug in your multiply method, I've edited my answers with two unit tests to reproduce the bug